# I can not get the real value of the width of the column HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, width

I have a particular problem in an HTML mine. Theoretically have a simple table with  and . The size of the columns I leave it to be rendered automatically in css and am using *white-space: nowrap;*. The problem is when I'll get on javascript the size of each column thead. I've tried several ways but it is not consistent with what is rendered. For example, in Chrome it shows the debug 65px but when I get this value it is always different.

[image]

I am using the javascript:

```
getBoundingClientRect().width
```

or

```
outerWidth(true)
```

I've tried everything but it always returns a different value. 49px is showing. I do not know what else to do, someone please. Thanks

Comment: Why don't u set a width for each column, it can happen if your font family/size is changing on different browsers

Comment: I need to get the column size after being rendered in different sizes of displays and different browsers

Comment: retrive the width of th using `outerWidth()`

Answer (score 1):

Note that [jQuery width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) will also take into account any padding or border you may have on that element

Comment: I created the example running, is correct in the example. The only difference I noticed in jsFiddle uses XHTML 1.0 and I'm using HTML5.  http://jsfiddle.net/aderbas/dXGRM/

Comment: I updated your fiddle. You were referencing all the fields not just the first one (ID), that's why you were getting inconsistent results.

Comment: But I need not only the first element of the row, I quoted the first to exemplify. In jsFiddle it is returning the correct width of the column. But in body of my html not. (I'm using HTML5)

Comment: I want a list with the size of each one so I'm picking up all in a loop

Comment: @StefanV. - The value returned by `.width()` does not include the padding and/or border. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/keDse/

Comment: I see, if you leave out the table column size and have a 100% width on your table, the columns will automatically adjust and fill the space. This is more of a CSS issue than a js one.